# How to Populate @State var using an Object?

Tags: class, swiftui, ios13

I'm trying to "bind" information from a Class with State elements like this:

```
let people = People(name: "Jonnathan", firstSurname: "Bree")

@State private var name = people.name
@State private var firstSurname = people.firstSurname
```

but when I try to make this I have this error:

**Cannot use instance member 'people' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

or

**Use of unresolved identifier 'self'**

if a try to add .self before the object

Thank you so much!

Comment: make them `lazy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
let people = People(name: "Jonnathan", firstSurname: "Bree")

@State private var name: String
@State private var firstSurname: String

init() {
    _name = State<String>(initialValue: people.name)
    _firstSurname = State<String>(initialValue: people.firstSurname)
}
```